# Template for enum

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How to specialize a template for all enums.
Just as it does `boost::serialization`.

In boost:

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive &AR, const unsigned int ver)
{
AR & enum__;
AR & int__;
AR & class__;
}
```

I need `operator&` for all enums:

```
struct A
{
void operator&(int obj){std::cout << "1";}
void operator&(unsigned int obj){std::cout << "2";}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value,void>::type operator&(T & obj) { std::cout << "Is enum" << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
void operator&(T & obj){obj.metod(); std::cout << "3";} // this operator not for enums
};

enum enum__{AAA,BBB};
enum enum2__{AAA2,BBB2};

int main()
{
A a;
enum__ d = AAA;
a & d;

enum2__ e = AAA2;
a & e;

std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Error C2593: Operator & is ambiguous

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum ? This can be combined with enable_if.

Comment: Get:
Error C2593: Operator & is ambiguous

Comment: Constrain the other overload on the opposite condition of not being an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error C2593: Operator & is ambiguous

Suppose, you pass an enum type to `operator&`. Then compiler will generate two versions of `operator&` with same function argument. That is why you got an ambiguous error. You should add a template specialization for *non-enums*:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value,void>::type
operator&(T & obj)
{
    obj.metod();
    std::cout << "3";
}
```